# runtime error of vlsift: input image contains a malformed PGM header

Tags: sift, vlfeat

I am trying to test sift detector of [vlfeat](http://www.vlfeat.org/) computer vision library by running sift.c file in src folder. I have successfully compiled and run the program. However, I got the error: ***the input image contains a malformed PGM header.*** I am sure it is not the problem of image file inputed. Could anyone explain that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This corresponds to the [`VL_ERR_PGM_INV_HEAD`](https://github.com/vlfeat/vlfeat/blob/edc378a722ea0d79e29f4648a54bb62f32b22568/src/sift.c#L479-L485) error code which is issued by the PGM decoder if the file is [less than 2 bytes](https://github.com/vlfeat/vlfeat/blob/edc378a722ea0d79e29f4648a54bb62f32b22568/vl/pgm.c#L177-L179) or has a [not supported or invalid magic number](https://github.com/vlfeat/vlfeat/blob/edc378a722ea0d79e29f4648a54bb62f32b22568/vl/pgm.c#L181-L199).

Please note that vlfeat only supports `P2` (ASCII) and `P5` (binary) formats. So you should inspect your magic to control if it fits these requirements, e.g.:

```
$ xxd -c 1 -l 2 foo.pgm
0000000: 50  P
0000001: 35  5

$ xxd -c 1 -l 2 bar.pbm
0000000: 50  P
0000001: 34  4
```

Here `foo.pgm` is valid (graymap in binary format) but `bar.pbm` is not supported by vlfeat (black & white bitmap in binary format).

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case what should I do for extracting features from my image. Actually, I have found another code, it use opencv to read image, then convert  the opencv result to vlfeat format.

Comment: You should use the OpenCV API used to write / encode an image into PGM, or convert your image a priori with e.g. ImageMagick: `convert foo.jpg foo.pgm`.